# Android Studio: Component is selected but Attributes editor says "No component selected"

Tags: android-studio, attributes, cardview

TL;DR: Although I can edit component attributes directly in XML (sanity check — I'm sane) the Attributes inspector pane claims nothing is selected. I.e. "It doesn't work."

I added a `CardView` to the main layout. It *does* show up in the Component Tree and in the Design Editor. I select the `CardView` in the Component Tree pane, but the Attributes pane says "No component selected".

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.2 on MacOS 10.15.1. This happens with all three `CardViews` (see screenshot).

Clicking the Text tab shows the XML for all the components, including the (so-called) "non-selected" one. Direct edits I make on the `CardView` XML entity *do* have effect, and the app builds and runs correctly, with all three `CardViews` showing up and scrolling in the `ScrollView`. So this is probably not a gradle issue (thanks autocorrect, it's not a cradle problem either). It's more like the build process knows about the views, but not the edit process.

I re-created the project from scratch, with the same result.

[image: screen shot of Android Studio]

Comment: Rebuilt the application. It will work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem today with a FloatingActionButton in Android Studio on macOS.

Restarting Android Studio was the solution for me.

Comment: Hm, well this morning the problem resolved for me too. After a weekend that included restarts and reboots... which was it? Of course I should have tried that on Friday. I guess I am getting too used to software that works... should know better! I will call your response the Answer.