# Android Studio - No components selected

Tags: android, components

I keep getting no components selected message when trying to edit my buttons in Android studio not sure why. Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWVnh.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio: Component is selected but Attributes editor says "No component selected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59221913/android-studio-component-is-selected-but-attributes-editor-says-no-component-s)

Comment: sometimes a simple restart should fix this.. but if this doesn't fix.. please check try  these answers also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview